# Get the data from "pins" on a Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet

There's a site with a `Leaflet` map that has pins on it. When I click on a pin, it makes a tooltip with some text in it. I want to get that text for each pin.

So I open Developer Tools. But where do I look?

What is the name of the JS variable that holds the text for each pin?

Answer (score 1):

Leaflet popups generally only appear one at a time inside a `.leaflet-popup-content` element. It sounds like you need to dig around the underlying code to see where the `bindPopup` calls are taking place to see the data in its original form. Or rig up some sort of automated process to click every marker, get the content with jQuery's `.text()`, then move onto the next marker.